# How do I allow post requests from my pages only?

Tags: php, ajax

Ok, the question is just theoretical but pretty simple, I don't want people to send post request from modified versions of my modules or jquery $.ajax scripts. Are there particular techniques to do that (mod rewrites configuration, .htacces, crc, and so on)?

Comment: needs some more clarification but it seems pretty interesting--are you saying reject certain post requests based on the *code* that was used to generate them?

Comment: well, yes, for instance

Comment: Have you considered/read about CSRF tokens?

Comment: [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP)

Comment: CSRF tokens or sessions are the usual approach

Comment: tokens look interesting, where may I find well explained documentation?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overly simple way to explain one common practice is that you generate a large random number or string at the time that the form is requested. This value is called a token, and since it is only used once, it is often called a nonce.

Store that token in the current session on the server and place it in the form as the value of a hidden field. When the user submits the form, compare the submitted token to the stored one.

You should also check the request headers to verify that the request looks like it is coming from the right page.

[owasp csrf cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet)